# Remove rows containing NA from the column with the least number of NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe that will eventually be converted into an `xts` object. The first column contains date data while all other columns contain numeric data. However, not all numeric columns have the same number of values/same length. Some columns have more rows containing NAs than others.

I want to filter my dataframe by removing the rows containing NAs in the column that has the least number of NAs but still retain the rows containing NAs for all other columns that I have selected. For example, the column grpA below has the least number of NAs. I would want to remove the first 2 rows of the dataframe that contains NAs but retain the values within grpB regardless of what they are.

What I have:

```
Date        grpA    grpB
2007-11-06  NA      NA
2007-11-07  NA      NA
2007-11-09  1.66    NA
2007-11-12  1.64    NA
2007-11-13  1.61    1.28
2007-11-14  1.60    1.30
2007-11-15  1.57    1.27
2007-11-16  1.56    1.25
2007-11-19  1.55    1.25
2007-11-20  1.55    1.25
2007-11-21  1.52    1.22
2007-11-22  1.50    1.21
2007-11-23  1.51    1.21
2007-11-26  1.52    1.25
2007-11-27  1.50    1.25
2007-11-28  1.50    1.23
2007-11-29  1.52    1.24
2007-11-30  1.56    1.25
2007-12-03  1.56    1.22
2007-12-04  1.56    1.23
```

What I want:

```
Date        grpA    grpB
2007-11-09  1.66    NA
2007-11-12  1.64    NA
2007-11-13  1.61    1.28
2007-11-14  1.60    1.30
2007-11-15  1.57    1.27
2007-11-16  1.56    1.25
2007-11-19  1.55    1.25
2007-11-20  1.55    1.25
2007-11-21  1.52    1.22
2007-11-22  1.50    1.21
2007-11-23  1.51    1.21
2007-11-26  1.52    1.25
2007-11-27  1.50    1.25
2007-11-28  1.50    1.23
2007-11-29  1.52    1.24
2007-11-30  1.56    1.25
2007-12-03  1.56    1.22
2007-12-04  1.56    1.23
```

A reproducible sample of the dataframe is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = structure(c(1194307200, 1194393600, 1194566400, 
                                    1194825600, 1194912000, 1194998400, 1195084800, 1195171200, 1195430400, 
                                    1195516800, 1195603200, 1195689600, 1195776000, 1196035200, 1196121600, 
                                    1196208000, 1196294400, 1196380800, 1196640000, 1196726400), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                           "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                 grpA = c(NA, NA, 1.66, 1.64, 1.61, 1.6, 1.57, 1.56, 1.55, 1.55, 1.52, 1.5, 1.51, 1.52, 1.5, 1.5, 1.52, 1.56, 1.56, 1.56), 
                 grpB = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.28, 1.3, 1.27, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.22, 1.21, 1.21, 1.25, 1.25, 1.23, 1.24, 1.25, 1.22, 1.23))
```

I have tried the `drop_na` function from the `tidyr` package and it works:

```
df2 <- drop_na(df, grpA)
```

However, I am going to use the above filtering in a Shiny App and I would not know in advance what columns users would select that has the least number of rows containing NAs in them.

I have tried the following to identify the column with the least number of rows containing NAs in them, but it provided me with the number of non-NA rows instead of the column name:

```
max(colSums(!is.na(df[-1])))
```

I have tried to extract out the name of the column using the following, but have encountered an error:

```
colnames(df)[which(colSums(!is.na(df[-1]))) == max(colSums(!is.na(df[-1])))]
```

I assumed that this was a straightforward task but it has become quite complicated. I would need the answer to be able to be used in a reactive expression in shiny.

Thanks and much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could first find the name of the column with minimum number of `NA`s and then remove `NA` rows from that column.

```
col <- names(which.min(colSums(is.na(df[-1]))))
df[!is.na(df[col]), ]


#         Date grpA grpB
#3  2007-11-09 1.66   NA
#4  2007-11-12 1.64   NA
#5  2007-11-13 1.61 1.28
#6  2007-11-14 1.60 1.30
#7  2007-11-15 1.57 1.27
#8  2007-11-16 1.56 1.25
#9  2007-11-19 1.55 1.25
#10 2007-11-20 1.55 1.25
#11 2007-11-21 1.52 1.22
#12 2007-11-22 1.50 1.21
#13 2007-11-23 1.51 1.21
#14 2007-11-26 1.52 1.25
#15 2007-11-27 1.50 1.25
#16 2007-11-28 1.50 1.23
#17 2007-11-29 1.52 1.24
#18 2007-11-30 1.56 1.25
#19 2007-12-03 1.56 1.22
#20 2007-12-04 1.56 1.23
```

which can be done in one-liner as well without creating additional variable

```
df[!is.na(df[names(which.min(colSums(is.na(df[-1]))))]), ]
```

---

Using the same logic a `dplyr` approach could be using `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   filter_at(df %>%
   summarise_at(-1, ~sum(is.na(.))) %>%
   which.min %>% names, ~!is.na(.))
```

Or using it with `tidyr::drop_na`

```
tidyr::drop_na(df, df %>%
                  summarise_at(-1, ~sum(is.na(.))) %>%
                  which.min %>% names)
```

Comment: Could I have an answer that can be piped into dplyr? I am still struggling to integrate this into my actual code. My actual code goes something like this df %>% select(Date, input$varnames) where input$varnames is from a `selectizeInput` with the possibility of multiple values

Comment: @DTYK Not a `shiny` expert but I added a `dplyr` version, check if it is helpful and if some way you can integrate it.

Comment: Tried the following but it still could not work:     df %>%
      select(Date, input$varnames) %>%
      drop_na(., . %>%
                summarise_at(-1, ~sum(is.na(.))) %>%
                which.min %>% names)

Comment: what is `input$varnames`? Why is it important? Are those the column names for which you want to check `NA` values ?

Comment: input$varnames is an input from a UI in shiny where user selects one or more variables/columns. It is read in as a character vector with 1 or more elements into the select statement. The error provided is "Warning: Error in : `. %>% summarise_at(-1, ~sum(is.na(.))) %>% which.min %>% names` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a function"

Comment: So if you don't want to calculate `NA` values for `Date` column can you try `tidyr::drop_na(df, df %>% summarise_at(input$varnames, ~sum(is.na(.))) %>% which.min %>% names)` ? Or if you also want to check for `Date` column try `tidyr::drop_na(df, df %>% summarise_at(Date, input$varnames, ~sum(is.na(.))) %>% which.min %>% names) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192289/discussion-between-dtyk-and-ronak-shah).